# Оформление вставки "раз"

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли так оформить следующее предложение?

И пусть ей какое-то время придётся грустить и даже иногда плакать, но ведь потом — раз, — и принц неожиданно вернётся к ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, так можно оформить. Примеры подобного оформления в литературе:

> Или просто — бац! — и полная тьма? (В. Набоков)
>
> ...Снова — бац! — и снова лежу, но уже вверх животом. (А.Куприн)

Только при таком оформлении лучше использовать восклицательный знак, наверное.

Comment: Так найдите авторитетные примеры с "раз", а не с междометием.

Comment: @oleedd Здесь "бац" выступает в функции сказуемого (как и "раз" в заданном вопросе). И я уже объяснял, что примеры с "раз" есть по Вашей ссылке.

Comment: Тогда это не вставка, а 2 интонационных тире. Я отвечал про оформление вставки, по Розенталю.

Comment: @oleedd Тогда прочитайте, пожалуйста, внимательнее вопрос и отвечайте на него. И отдельно можете указать на то, что употребляемая терминология некорректна с Вашей точки зрения. Вы же вместо ответа дали комментарий и этим сбиваете с толку автора вопроса.

Comment: Тогда здесь "*раз*" каким-то междометием получается.

Comment: @oleedd Будет лучше, если Вы зададите отдельный вопрос по поводу употребления **бац** и **раз** в функции сказуемого. Вряд ли уместно долго спорить об этом в комментариях.

Comment: Говорю про часть речи, а не про сказуемое.

Comment: @oleedd Посмотрите [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%86). И про "раз" тоже. Простите, это мой последний комментарий здесь (не люблю злоупотреблять нарушениями).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы так написала:

*И пусть ей какое-то время придётся грустить и даже иногда плакать, но ведь потом  **раз — и** принц неожиданно вернётся к ней.*

По образцу: [Раз, два — и в дамки](https://gufo.me/dict/colloquialisms/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7,_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Answer (score 1):

При изъятии вставки смысл не должен страдать:
*И пусть ей какое-то время придётся грустить и даже иногда плакать, но ведь потом и принц неожиданно вернётся к ней.* || Не сильно корректно.

Часть после вставки не должна исходить из неё. Вставка - это как дополнение, уточнение, комментарий к предыдущему тексту.

Comment: Как тогда следует поставить знаки препинания (без изменения предложения)?

Comment: Есть варианты с одним тире (лучше перед И, чтобы подчеркнуть то, что произойдёт потом): http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=потом+раз

Comment: Обратите внимание, что среди примеров по ссылке есть и точно такое оформление — с двумя тире.

Comment: Смотрю, что в таких примерах при изъятии структура предложения остаётся корректной.

Comment: "А потом ― раз!  ― и уснул." Изъятие ничуть не корректнее, чем "но потом — раз! — и принц вернулся".

Comment: Тут вполне изымается: *А потом и уснул.* А в данном предложении мне изъятие не показалось корректным. Слово "*неожиданно*" как бы ссылается на "*раз*".